# Django returning status code 400 with error message from test

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to run tests from my DJango app, but I'm getting

```
FAIL: test_login (authentication.tests.AuthTestCase)
line 32, in test_login
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 400 != 200
```

This is the code of my test:

```
    def test_login(self):
        data = {'usuario_email': 'voter1', 'password1': '123'}
        response = self.client.post('/authentication/login/', data, format='json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        message = response.json().get('message')
        self.assertEqual(message, 'Autentificación correcta')
```

And this is the code for login:

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            usuario_email = cd.get('usuario_email')
            password1 = cd.get('password1')
            user = None
            if usuario_email and '@' in usuario_email:
                # Si es un correo electrónico, busca por email
                user = User.objects.filter(email=usuario_email).first()
            else:
                # Si no es un correo, busca por nombre de usuario
                user = User.objects.filter(username=usuario_email).first()

            if user is not None:
                user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password1)
                if user is not None and user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    print("Usuario logueado correctamente")
                    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Autentificacion correcta'})
                else:
                    return JsonResponse({'message': 'Cuenta desactivada o credenciales inválidas'})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Inicio de sesión inválido'})

    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Solicitud incorrecta'}, status=400)
```

I have tried manually to login, and I get

```
{"message": "Autentificacion correcta"}
```

The URL I use for login is http://127.0.0.1:8000/login-form and the URL to make the POST action: http://127.0.0.1:8000/authentication/login/

I have tried to debug the test but I always get

```
<JsonResponse status_code=400, "application/json">
```

I have also try to change the values of test data for actual users registered, but it didn't work.

Comment: What about the CSRF cookie? Do you use it?

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you're using the endpoint /authentication/login/, but in your manual test, you mention using /login-form. Make sure you are using the correct endpoint in your test.

Also, make sure that your test data matches the expected format. In your login view, you are looking for usuario_email and password1, but in your test, you are sending usuario_email and password. Ensure that the keys in your test data match the expected keys in your view.

Comment: Hi, in the url /login-form I only render the html. The post action is made by /authentication/login/. Also, I have tried to change my test data with username, user_email, password, password1 etc.. and it doesn't work